# Como criar um sistema de controle de permissões

Tags: php, html

Tenho um sistema em PHP/HTML e quero implantar um sistema de permissão.

Funcionaria da seguinte maneira:

1) Tenho algumas páginas que algumas funcionalidades só podem vistas por cargos mais altos. Exemplo: tenho uma página de busca, para um usuário normal, quero que ele pesquise somente pelo nome. Já um gerente, teria vários filtros disponíveis.

2) Ter alguma página para setar essas permissões. Usando o exemplo da busca: Administrador vai nessa página e seta determinado usuário para também poder pesquisar por cpf.

Não quero um sistema pronto. Quero alguma ideia para onde ir, o que buscar, se existe algum framework.

Comment: ziad.ali segue aqui [uma das várias maneiras de se fazer isso](http://pastebin.com/xZ4VKT1X). Bom estudos.

Comment: @ziad.ali só para não te deixar na mão sugiro a leitura desses tópicos: [Criando controle de acesso com PHP e MySQL](http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-controle-de-acesso-com-php-e-mysql/28123) e [Como criar um Sistema de Login com Níveis de Permissão](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/como-criar-um-sistema-de-login-com-niveis-de-permissao/)

Comment: @KaduAmaral A pergunta está reaberta. Ziad, mesmo assim seria legal você [edit] a pergunta é acrescentar mais informações, como se o seu sistema já tem cadastro de usuários, se considera grupos de usuários, se a parte de login e autenticação já existe e como foi implementada, qual a base de dados utilizada, etc.

Comment: Como a pergunta é antiga, a resposta será nova... O caminho a seguir seria usar PHP com Framework Laravel, busque algo na net como ACL Laravel. Veja esse video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJRt0BDF0Do

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Criando um sistema de permissão

Primeiro precisamos da tabela de usuários:

```
usuarios
  id - INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  nome - VARCHAR
  email - VARCHAR
  senha - VARCHAR
  ativo - INT (0 - Inativo / 1 - Ativo)
  nivel - (0 - usuário comum / 1 - Administrador / 2 - Desenvolvedor / 3 - Administrador e Desenvolvedor)
```

<sub>Se o usuário for um administrador ou desenvolvedor ignore as validações de acesso, da forma que achar melhor.</sub>

Agora temos que mapear as páginas do sistema

```
paginas
  id - PIRMARY KEY -- Código único que identifique a página (pode até ser o nome do arquivo ou um INT AUTO_INCREMENT)
  arquivo - VARCHAR -- Nome do arquivo
  nome - VARCHAR
  sistema - INT -- (0 - Não / 1 - Sim) é uma página do sistema como por exemplo uma página Erro 404 / Acesso Restrito / Etc...
```

<sub>Salve todas as páginas do sistema no banco de dados, e coloque no arquivo uma variável com o ID de cada uma</sub>

Agora a tabela de acesso:

```
acesso_paginas
  usuario_id
  pagina_id
  consultar (0 - Não / 1 - Sim)
  incluir (0 - Não / 1 - Sim)
  editar (0 - Não / 1 - Sim)
  excluir (0 - Não / 1 - Sim)
```

<sub>Utilize o campo `consultar`, para ver se o usuário tem acesso a essa página, e os demais campos você pode colocar nos botões de inclusão/exclusão e nos campos caso o usuário não possa editar.</sub>

Se você quer que cada campo tenha um acesso diferente, para cada usuário, você terá que mapear todos os campos do seu sistema, algo que dá muito trabalho, mas poderia fazer assim:

```
fields
  id - INT PRIMARY KEY
  nome - VARCHAR
  pagina_id
```

<sub>Para cada campo de cada página, salve um registro no banco de dados que identifique aquele campo.</sub>

E o acesso:

```
acesso_fields
  field_id
  pagina_id
  usuario_id
  visivel (0 - Não / 1 - Sim)
  editavel (0 - Não / 1 - Sim)
```

<sub>Utilize o campo `visivel` para exibir o campo no sistema e o campo editável para habilitar ou desabilitar.</sub>

### Regra

Sempre que um usuário acessar alguma página, você busca a página na tabela `acesso_paginas` e verifica se ele tem acesso a aquela página. Se o usuário tiver acesso, você verifica qual o tipo de acesso, e aplica as devidas regras de acordo com o tipo de acesso. Exemplo, se ele só pode consultar a página apenas exiba o necessário com todos os campos desabilitados.

Se você for validar os campos, busque na tabela `acesso_fields` pelo `ID` da página e busque todos os campos da página em um único `SELECT`, e faça uma função para buscar nos dados retornados o campo e as permissões.

### Exemplo

Acesso à página:

```
$pageid = 36;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM acesso_paginas WHERE usuario_id = {$_SESSION['user']['id']} AND pagina_id = {$pageid};"
// Receba o resultado e verifique o tipo de acesso.

if ($res['consultar'] == '0') {
   header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
   exit;
}

.
.
.

if ($res['excluir'] == '1') echo '<button type="button" id="excluir" class="button">Excluir</button>';
```

Acesso ao campo:

```
$pageid = 36;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM acesso_fields WHERE usuario_id = {$_SESSION['user']['id']} AND pagina_id = {$pageid};"
// Receba os dados

function FieldAccess($dados){
   // Faça uma função quer percorra o array recebido do baco e retorne os devidos acessos ao campo
   // Pode usar códigos do tipo

   // 0 - Sem acesso total (não exibe campo)
   if ($dados[$x]['visivel'] == '0') return 0;  

   // 1 - Acesso visual (apenas exibe o campo, mas não permite editar o valor)
   if ($dados[$x]['visivel'] == '1' && $dados[$x]['editavel'] == '0' ) return 1; 

   // 2 - Acesso total
   // if ($dados[$x]['visivel'] == '1' && $dados[$x]['editavel'] == '1' ) return 2; 
   // Sempre retorne 2 para exibir normalmente os campos que não estiverem 
   // cadastrados no acesso do usuário
   return 2;
}

.
.
.

<?php
  $acesso = FieldAccess(348);
  if ($acesso > 0){
?>
<input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="Informe o CPF"<?=($acesso == '1' ? ' readonly' : '')?>>
<?php
  }
?>
```

---

**Obs.: Muito cuidado a excessiva validação de campos, pois pode acabar prejudicando a performance do sistema. Use apenas em casos necessários.**

Comment: Muito obrigado @KaduAmaral, lendo aqui parece ser exatamente o que eu quero. Me parece um pouco trabalhoso, mas resolveria o problema. Irei deixar como resposta certa aqui e tentarei implementar.

Comment: Eu já utilizo um esquema bem similar em um projeto que tenho, só não utilizo a validação de campos individuais, pois realmente é muito trabalhoso, uso apenas a validação das páginas (consultar, inserir, editar, excluir) que já me serve bem. Se estiver com dificuldades de implementar, poste aqui, ou se necessário faça uma nova pergunta, caso o problema seja bem específico.

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta é ampla pois existem muitos caminhos para se implementar um sistema de controle de permissões. Mesmo assim, vou tentar mostrar um dos caminhos possíveis, em linhas gerais.

O controle de permissões leva em conta *quem acessa* (usuários e/ou grupos), *o que é acessado* (páginas, partes de páginas, campos de formulário etc) e, muitas vezes, *como* isso pode ser acessado (por exemplo, no caso de campos, se o acesso é somente leitura).

Levando isso em conta, o primeiro passo é modelar sua base de dados para comportar essas entidades. No mínimo será necessário uma tabela de usuários, uma tabela de "acessíveis" (os objetos com permissão controlada), e uma tabela de permissões relacionando os dois, registrando quem tem acesso a quê.

Modelada a base, eu criaria uma camada de abstração do controle de acesso, no seu caso em PHP, de modo que fique simples para o desenvolvedor "perguntar" ao sistema se determinado usuário possui acesso a determinado objeto. Considerando seu exemplo, ao montar o HTML da *view* de pesquisa, você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
if(acesso->permitido($id_usuario, 'busca_cpf')) {
    // Desenha o campo de busca por CPF
}
```

Naturalmente o controle de acesso não deve ser feito só na view. No código que de fato efetua a busca, é recomendável fazer a mesma verificação ao receber um CPF para busca, antes de montar a consulta que traz os registros por CPF. Desta maneira, se algum usuário sem acesso tentar enganar o sistema passando um CPF, a busca não seria feita.

Comment: Como eu disse, estas são apenas linhas gerais, mas espero que te ajude a encontrar um caminho.

Comment: Essa é uma dúvida que tenho, pois faço a validação baseado no ID da página, porém o arquivo que recebe os dados é um arquivo abstrato que pode receber dados de várias páginas. Então como eu faria essa validação ao receber os dados?

Comment: Da mesma maneira, verifique se o usuário logado tem acesso a uma funcionalidade específica (não a uma página) @KaduAmaral.

Answer (score 4):

Estou trabalhando sobre um site em PHP que tem mas o menos 6500 possibilidade de acesso. O principio e um "variação" de um conceito de "Assembly Language" e chamamos isso de XGen.

Cada pagina do site tem um String "Xgen" composto de valores do tipo:
Exemplo:

```
pagina A -> 01000
pagina B -> 00100
pagine C -> 00001
```

cada usuário tem uma "string" do mesmo tipo. Exemplo:

```
Marcello -> 01100
José -> 00001
```

Quando Marcello chega na pagina A, os sistema da uma olhado nos 2 valores:

```
Da pagina -> 01000
Do usario -> 01100
```

resultado: Marcello tem direto de acesso nesta pagina

Mas Marcello, neste exemplo, nao tem acesso na pagina C

Você pode "ameliorar" o principio, usando valores diferentes.
Exemplo:

```
001000 significa simplismente accesso
002000 significa accesar + editar
etc...
```

No meu sistema, cada Xgen tem 100 valores: para cada página e para cada Sapador-Bombeiro (e um sistema de admin de quarteéis). Eu posso determinar acesso com grau, nível de formação, idade etc.

Answer (score -3):

O sistema consistirá em um login simples, validado por usuário e senha (encriptada) contra uma tabela no banco de dados e armazenando os dados na sessão. Haverão dois níveis de acesso para os nossos usuários: normal (1) e administrador (2).

**Criando a Tabela MySQL**

Você pode executar esse código MySQL para criar a nossa tabela de usuários que tem 7 campos: id, nome, usuario, senha, niveis, ativo e cadastro:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    `usuario` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
    `senha` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
    `email` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
    `nivel` INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `ativo` BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `cadastro` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `usuario` (`usuario`),
    KEY `nivel` (`nivel`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ;
```

Com isso você já tem uma tabela pronta para o nosso tutorial… Rode esse script se quiser alimentar a tabela com alguns usuários de teste:

```
INSERT INTO `usuarios` VALUES (NULL, 'Usuário Teste', 'demo', SHA1( 'demo' ), 'usuario@demo.com.br', 1, 1, NOW( ));

INSERT INTO `usuarios` VALUES (NULL, 'Administrador Teste', 'admin', SHA1( 'admin' ), 'admin@demo.com.br', 2, 1, NOW( ));
```

Como vocês podem perceber, o nosso campo de senha tem 40 caracteres e quando cadastramos os usuários testes usamos `SHA1(‘{senha}’)` isso significa que usaremos uma senha encriptada… Se você quiser saber mais sobre sha1 veja esse artigo: Criptografia no PHP usando md5, sha1 e base64.

**O formulário de Login em XHTML**

Vamos criar agora o nosso formulário que será onde o visitante entrará com os dados e será mandado para a pagina validacao.php onde os dados serão validados (ohh).

```
<!-- Formulário de Login -->
<form action="validacao.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Dados de Login</legend>
    <label for="txUsuario">Usuário</label>
    <input type="text" name="usuario" id="txUsuario" maxlength="25" />
    <label for="txSenha">Senha</label>
    <input type="password" name="senha" id="txSenha" />
    <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Como esse artigo não é uma aula sobre formulários e método POST eu vou pular a parte que fala sobre os names desses inputs e a relação deles com o PHP em si.

**A validação dos dados**

Já temos o banco de dados e o formulário de login… Agora vamos começar a fazer a validação. Os próximos códigos deverão ser colocados dentro do validacao.php que irá tratar os dados recebidos do formulário:

Primeiro de tudo nós precisamos verificar se o usuário de fato preencheu algo no formulário, caso contrário mandamos ele de volta para o *index.php*:

```
<?php
// Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)

if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['usuario']) OR empty($_POST['senha']))) {
    header("Location: index.php"); exit;
}


?>
```

Com isso, todo código que vier depois desse if estará seguro de que os dados foram preenchidos no formulário.

Agora nós iremos abrir uma conexão com o MySQL mas essa conexão pode ser feita de outra forma, até antes do if se você preferir… Depois de abrir a conexão nós iremos transmitir os dois valores inseridos pelo visitante (usuário e senha) para novas variáveis e usaremos o `mysql_real_escape_string()` para evitar erros no MySQL.

```
<?php

// Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['usuario']) OR empty($_POST['senha']))) {
    header("Location: index.php"); exit;
}

// Tenta se conectar ao servidor MySQL
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
// Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
mysql_select_db('usuarios') or trigger_error(mysql_error());

$usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

?>
```

Agora é hora de validar os dados contra a tabela de usuários:

```
<?php

// Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['usuario']) OR empty($_POST['senha']))) {
    header("Location: index.php"); exit;
}
// Tenta se conectar ao servidor MySQL
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
// Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
mysql_select_db('usuarios') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

// Validação do usuário/senha digitados
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome`, `nivel` FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`usuario` = '". $usuario ."') AND (`senha` = '". sha1($senha) ."') AND (`ativo` = 1) LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
} else {
    // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

?>
```

Repare que estamos buscando registros que tenham o usuário igual ao digitado pelo visitante e que tenham uma senha igual a versão SHA1 da senha digitada pelo visitante… Também buscamos apenas por registros de usuários que estejam ativos, assim quando você precisar remover um usuário do sistema, mas não pode simplesmente excluir o registro é só trocar o valor da coluna ativo pra zero. ;)

A consulta gerada fica mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT `id`, `nome`, `nivel` FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`usuario` = 'a') AND (`senha` = 'e9d71f5ee7c92d6dc9e92ffdad17b8bd49418f98') AND (`ativo` = 1) LIMIT 1
```

Depois de rodar a consulta (*query*) nós verificamos se o número de resultados encontrados (ou não) é diferente de um, caso seja é exibida uma mensagem de erro acompanhada de um `exit` que finaliza o *script*… Caso ele encontre apenas um resultado nós temos o nosso usuário e já puxamos o seu ID, nome e nível de acesso do banco de dados.

**Salvando os dados na sessão**

Agora nós precisamos salvar os dados encontrados na sessão pois eles serão utilizados mais tarde, em outras páginas e eles precisam “persistir” até lá… Depois de salvar os dados na sessão nós iremos redirecionar o visitante para uma página restrita:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
} else {
    // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];
    // Redireciona o visitante
    header("Location: restrito.php"); exit;
}
```

**Verificando se o usuário está logado**

Nosso sistema de *login* está quase completo! Agora só precisamos verificar se o usuário está logado no sistema e se o seu o nível de acesso condiz com o da página… Vamos agora escrever um pequeno bloco de PHP no início do arquivo *restrito.php* (que só deve ser acessado por usuários logados):

```
<?php

// A sessão precisa ser iniciada em cada página diferente
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

// Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID'])) {
    // Destrói a sessão por segurança
    session_destroy();
    // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
    header("Location: index.php"); exit;
}

?>

<h1>Página restrita</h1>

<p>Olá, <?php echo $_SESSION['UsuarioNome']; ?>!</p>
```

Pronto meu amigo! O seu sistema de login está pronto para funcionar… Só vamos fazer alguns incrementos para ele ficar mais “usável”… Agora você vai ver como fazer a verificação de usuário logado e de nível de acesso, por exemplo para uma página onde apenas os administradores possam ter acesso:

```
<?php

// A sessão precisa ser iniciada em cada página diferente
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

$nivel_necessario = 2;

// Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID']) OR ($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] < $nivel_necessario)) {
    // Destrói a sessão por segurança
    session_destroy();
    // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
    header("Location: index.php"); exit;
}

?>
```

**Código de Logout**

O arquivo *logout.php* é tão simples que pode ter uma linha só:

```
<?php session_start(); session_destroy(); header("Location: index.php"); exit; ?>
```

Ou se você preferir, uma versão mais extensa:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Inicia a sessão
    session_destroy(); // Destrói a sessão limpando todos os valores salvos
    header("Location: index.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante
?>
```

Fonte: [Thiago Belem](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/como-criar-um-sistema-de-login-com-niveis-de-permissao/)

Comment: Eu acho que ele quer saber algo um pouco mais complexo do que apenas um sistema de login... Ou seja `quero implantar um sistema de permissão` e `Ter alguma página para setar essas permissões`. Então entendi que mesmo um usuário de nível comum pode ter alguns privilégios que outros do mesmo nível não tenha.

Comment: Exatamento isso KaduAmaral.

Comment: Eu concordo @KaduAmaral porém com melhores perguntas ele tera melhores respostas. Com o que passei ele tem uma noção de como começar a ideia é essa não dar a resposta e sim um caminho para seguir.

Comment: `a ideia é essa não dar a resposta e sim um caminho para seguir.` ... Otto desculpa a sinceridade, mas pra mim seu post pareceu mais a 'resposta' e não um caminho a seguir

Comment: é um caminho para ele seguir somente uma abordagem geral de como utilizar de como fazer se entendeu como resposta esta enganado

Comment: mas @MarceloBonifazio caso tenha um caminho melhor para ele seguir fique a vontade de postar

Comment: Fala @Bacco sem tirar nem por todos estamos aqui para complementar.