# checar se está logado numa session específica

Tags: php, html, session

Boa tarde, pessoal. Estou com um problema e não imagino lugar melhor para resolver isso do que aqui:

Tenho um site que tanto logins de administradores com acessos à funções e membros comuns acessarão. A dúvida é em como vou separar para somente exibir as funções  para os administradores, pois até então estava usando isso:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["senha"])){
    session_write_close();
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit; //encerra todas as funções e leva para o index
}
else{
    echo "<center>Você está logado.</center>";
}
```

Mas agora que coloquei o cadastro de membros não sei o que fazer. Obrigado!

Comment: tem algo no cadastro que identifique que o tipo de usuário ?

Comment: Acho que você está procurando por [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35092/como-criar-um-sistema-de-controle-de-permiss%C3%B5es)...

Comment: @gustavox é isso mesmo! só estou tendo dificuldade em traduzir a parte do código em mysql para comandos do postgres...

Comment: Então acho que é melhor você fazer outra pergunta, colocando nela o código mysql que quer converter em comandos postgres...