# Como redirecionar páginas php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho um sistema de login num programa `PHP` que pretendo que ele reencaminhe os utilizadores para diferentes páginas dependendo do seu perfil. Existe uma tabela login que tem um campo chamado "`perfil`" que ou está a `0` ou a `1`. O objetivo é encaminhar os utilizadores dependendo do seu perfil para diferentes páginas. Como consigo fazê-lo de uma forma simples?

```
<?php
    include ("incs/ligacao.inc.php");
    include('session.php');
    $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
    session_start();

        $utilizador = $mysqli->query("SELECT perfil from login where username='$user_check'");
        $result = $utilizador->fetch_assoc();

        if($result['perfil'] == 0){
      header('Location: menu.php');
        }


    elseif($result['perfil'] == 1){
        header('Location:menu.php');
    }



?>
```

Fica sempre na página de login ao tentar fazer esta verificação

Comment: Possível duplicata => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35092/como-criar-um-sistema-de-controle-de-permiss%C3%B5es

Comment: Se você ser um echo no $utilizador o que ele retorna?

Comment: não consigo verificar por causa da session, mas fazendo a query no mysql retorna 1

Comment: Falta o `fetch`. Você está comparando um objeto, por isso não entra no `if`

Comment: mas mesmo com o fetch ele volta sempre para a página de login. Já introduzi o fetch e mesmo assim não entra no if

Comment: Atualize a questão com o uso do `fetch`, mostre como ficou.

Comment: com o fetch fica desta forma, o problema é que quando introduzo o user ele volta sempre á página de login

Comment: Dê um `var_dump( $result )` e diga o que aparece.

Comment: Hey, eu tenho um sistema de login bem parecido com o seu nessa pergunta, se quiser usar, a vontade: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241731/login-com-sistema-de-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 4):

Você pode facilmente usar a sintaxe de cabeçalho "Location", algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
header('Location: /paginadestino.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Falta usar o `fetch_assoc` para recuperar o valor do *perfil*. O comando `$mysqli-> query( ... )` retorna um objeto e não a row.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `perfil` from login where username='$user_check'");
$result = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Agora basta usar `$result['perfil']` para verificar o tipo de perfil e fazer o redirecionamento como o memso código que está usando.

```
if($result['perfil'] == 0)
{
    header('Location: aaa.php');
}

elseif($result['perfil'] == 1)
{
    header('Location:bbb.php');
}
```

Comment: Dê um `var_dump( $result )` e diga o que aparece.

Answer (score 2):

Para redirecionar de acordo com o perfil podes fazer:

```
if($perfil == 0)
  header('Location: /pagina_perfil_0.php');
elseif($perfil == 1)
  header('Location: /pagina_perfil_1.php');
```

Ou assim:

```
switch ($perfil) {
    case 0: header('Location: /pagina_perfil_0.php');
      break;
    case 1: header('Location: /pagina_perfil_1.php');
      break;
}
```

Obs: Caso tenha mais perfis basta ir adicionando aos laços.

Espero que ajude.
Qualquer dúvida poste ai.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. eu não estou a conseguir redirecionar, faço esta query ( $utilizador = $mysqli->query("SELECT perfil from login where username='$user_check'"); )
 $rst = $utilizador->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
mas depois não consigo aceder

Comment: Você não esta conseguindo recuperar o perfil cadastrado então? Se for o caso coloque na pergunta as informações sobre a tabela para ajudarmos a montar a query.

Comment: já edeitei o post com o codigo da página para validar o tipo de utilizador. O problema é que não sai da página do index :/

Answer (score 2):

Defina aonde você precisa. É só usar.

```
function redirect($url)
{
    header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: +1, acho  mais favorável a retuilização

Answer (score -3):

Gente preciso de ajuda... Criei um programa usando Notepad++ e preciso de 
ajuda.Preciso redirecionar para outra pagina que deve ser exibida os dados do cadastro da pessoa ajuda plis

```
<body>
<h1>Bem vindo a rede social 3.0</h1>
<h2>Informe os seus dados para continuar</h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr align="left" width="400" noshade="noshade" />
<form action="processar.php" method="post" id="frmLogin">
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>


     <td width="60" align="right">Nome:</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtNome" id="txtNome" />
        </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Idade:</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtIdade" id="txtIdade" />
        </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="60" align="right">Endereço:</td>
        <td><label>
    <input type="text" name="txtEndereço" id="txtEndereço" />
        </label></td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>

        </label></td>
        <td width="60" align="right">Salário:</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtSalário" id="txtSalário" />
        </label></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            </label></td>
        <td width="60" align="right">Tempo de Serviço:</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtTempoDeServiço" id="txtTempoDeServiço" />
        </label></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
     </label></td>
        <td width="60" align="right">Registrado Em:</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtRegistradoEm" id="txtRegistradoEm" />
        </label></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" value="Entrar" />
        </label></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Meu caro, utilizou o campo de resposta para fazer uma pergunta. Procure na página um botão "Faça uma Pergunta" e clique nele para fazer uma nova pergunta. E utilize as tags para classificar o tema.