# get content random url dentro de arquivo txt

Tags: php

Eu tenho vários arquivos txt dentro de uma pasta

```
/pasta/1.txt
/pasta/2.txt
```

Etc...

Dentro desses arquivos contém várias urls

```
Exemplo:
/pasta/1.txt

conteúdo:
www.site.com/nome/jose.html
www.site.com/nome/joao.html



/pasta/2.txt
conteúdo:
www.site.com/nome/maria.html
www.site.com/nome/juliana.html
```

Eu preciso de um código que ao acessar a url: 
    www.site.com.br/sortear.php 
ele acesse a pasta /pasta/ escolhe um dos arquivos (.txt) de forma random e capture uma URL (Ex: www.site.com/nome/jose.html) e acesse essa url.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Marcelo, coloque o código que você esta tentando usar para criar essa tarefa, deste modo as pessoas poderão te ajudar a encontrar o problema porque pelo que parece você esta pedindo pra fazer para você, e isso não vai acontecer...

Comment: E o que você quer dizer com "acesse essa URL"? O PHP deve fazer uma requisição para a página ou o usuário ser redirecionado?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, redirecionado para a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é bem simples de ser feito, existem N maneira de fazer isso.

Primeiro precisa obter os arquivos, a *lista* de arquivos que possui na pasta, neste caso supondo que tudo esteja dentro de `/pasta/` e estão em `.txt` poderia usar o [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) para obter o caminhos dos arquivos e depois selecionar um deles usando algum gerador.

```
$Arquivos = glob('pasta/*.txt');
$ArquivoEscolhido = $Arquivos[random_int(0, count($Arquivos) - 1)];
```

Pronto, usamos o [`random_int`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.random-int.php) para selecionar um dos arquivos, o `$ArquivosEscolhidos` terá o caminho de um dos arquivos, que foi selecionado aleatoriamente.

Agora basta ler os arquivos, neste caso usando o [`file()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php) e selecionar uma das linhas, poderia fazer:

```
$Linhas = file($ArquivoEscolhido);
$LinhaEscolhida = $Linhas[random_int(0, count($Linhas) - 1)];
```

Pronto, agora já selecionou uma linha e pode exibir usando `echo $LinhaEscolhida`, por exemplo ou se quiser redicionar use o `header()` [veja isto.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135324/como-redirecionar-p%C3%A1ginas-php)

---

*O `random_int` está apenas disponível no PHP 7 e superior. Você também mas poderia usar Mersenne Twister, via `mt_rand` ou `shuffle`, ou usar um LFSR/LGC via `rand`, se usar PHP 7 ou inferior. Também pode usar o `scandir` com algumas alterações no código.*

Comment: Consegui utilizando o que você encaminhou